# Cannot seem to use “Page Up” when running Ubuntu within VirtualBox on a MacBook Pro

Tags: ubuntu, mac, virtualbox

I have MacBook Pro and I'm running Ubuntu server inside VirtualBox and don't seem to have <kbd>page up</kbd> functionality.

How can I scroll up and see missed lines in the terminal when running running Ubuntu server inside VirtualBox?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you do <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Fn</kbd> + <kbd>↑</kbd>?

If I remember correctly, <kbd>Fn</kbd> + <kbd>↑</kbd> is page up on macOS.

Comment: Both do not work

Answer (score 0):

Finally solved this by running the "screen" command, then pressed control+a, then esc, which then allowed me to either us page up/page down to scroll up/down by the whole screen, or up/down arrow line by line.